# Heat map with opacity gradient

Tags: r, excel, wolfram-mathematica, opacity, heatmap

I have two heat maps that I want to overlay to create one combined map. I am looking for a way to make an opacity/alpha gradient instead of a color gradient; that is, transparent->blue instead of white->blue.

I have access to a lot of plotting software (R, mathematica, gnuplot, grace, excel, etc) but I just don't know what program is capable of this kind of gradient.

So far, the best that I can do is make two heat maps in excel, then make one slightly transparent and overlay it on the other. The problem is, this muddles the colors so that the dark shades are no longer dark. This figure can be found here: [Excel Heat map overlays](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47760934/Heatmap_question2.png)

Thank you in advance for any help!

Scott